# How to prepare the correct json string with square brackets?

Tags: r

I have the following data

```
library(rjson)
body= list(orderBy=list(dir="",
                    prop=""),
       pageNumber=0 ,
       size=1,
       data=list(numeroIdentificacion ="12345",
                 tipoDocumento=list (id="0" ,
                                     codigo="",
                                     nombre="",
                                     descripcion=""),
                 numeroIdentificacionCuidador=""
       )
```

)

I require to convert it to a JSON format:

```
"{\"orderBy\":[{\"dir\":\"\",\"prop\":\"\"}],\"pageNumber\":0,\"size\":1,\"data\":{\"numeroIdentificacion\":\"12345\",\"tipoDocumento\":{\"id\":0,\"codigo\":\"\",\"nombre\":\"\",\"descripcion\":\"\"},\"numeroIdentificacionCuidador\":\"\"}}"
```

But when running  `toJSON(body)` , this will yield:

```
"{\"orderBy\":{\"dir\":\"\",\"prop\":\"\"},\"pageNumber\":0,\"size\":1,\"data\":{\"numeroIdentificacion\":\"12345\",\"tipoDocumento\":{\"id\":\"0\",\"codigo\":\"\",\"nombre\":\"\",\"descripcion\":\"\"},\"numeroIdentificacionCuidador\":\"\"}}"
```

As you can see, there are some square brackets missing as well as the final formatting.

Comment: Which package are you using for `toJSON`?

Comment: `library(rjson)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need the extra square braces around the `orderBy` part, you'll need to embed that in a list.

Try

```
body= list(orderBy=list(list(dir="", prop="")),
           pageNumber=0 ,
           size=1,
           data=list(numeroIdentificacion ="12345",
                     tipoDocumento=list (id="0" ,
                                         codigo="",
                                         nombre="",
                                         descripcion=""),
                     numeroIdentificacionCuidador=""
           ))
```

Then you can do

```
jsonlite::toJSON(body, auto_unbox = TRUE)
```

to get

```
{"orderBy":[{"dir":"","prop":""}],"pageNumber":0,"size":1,"data":{"numeroIdentificacion":"12345","tipoDocumento":{"id":"0","codigo":"","nombre":"","descripcion":""},"numeroIdentificacionCuidador":""}}
```

or

```
rjson::toJSON(body)
```

to get

```
[1] "{\"orderBy\":[{\"dir\":\"\",\"prop\":\"\"}],\"pageNumber\":0,\"size\":1,\"data\":{\"numeroIdentificacion\":\"12345\",\"tipoDocumento\":{\"id\":\"0\",\"codigo\":\"\",\"nombre\":\"\",\"descripcion\":\"\"},\"numeroIdentificacionCuidador\":\"\"}}"
```